# how to get rid of grand totals and totals column in pivot table view-ms access

Tags: pivot, ms-access-2010, pivot-table

I have a form of type pivot table in ms access. I want to get rid of grand totals and totals column in the pivot table view.
I tried selecting the column and deleting it but doesn't work.
Please suggest an alternate way. Thank you!!

Comment: It is what it is. Don't think can modify that structure. I have never used pivot tables/forms. This feature removed in Access 2013.

Comment: I'm using Offfice 2010. Was it working in ms access 2010

Comment: Yes, still in Access 2010. Access 2013 and up should be able to open forms and tables set for Pivot view if property set in earlier version.

Comment: i figured it out. I just had to right click on the column name and select subtotal.Thank you.